# Can't process Firebase acquired values with async and Foreach

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, foreach, async-await

I want to process the value obtained by Firebase with Forach.
To processed in order, async, await was used.

```
const sleep = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
 async function () {
   var snapshot = await firebase.database().ref("/path/").once("value")
   snapshot.forEach(async function (childSnapshot) {
       await sleep(1000)
       console.log(snapshot.val)
   })
 }
```

However, as a result only the first item of the first is processed. 
That is, Foreach is not working.
Foreach will work if you remove async, await.
How can we make them compatible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You won't be able to use forEach, since it requires that you pass a function, and it won't use the promise returned by it (which is always what an async function returns).  Instead, convert the database child nodes into an array and iterate it with for/of:

```
async function () {
  const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref("/path/").once("value")
  const array = []
  snapshot.forEach(child => array.push(child))
  for (const child of array) {
     await sleep(1000)
     console.log(snapshot.val)
  }
}
```

Also note that the snapshot returned by Firebase isn't an array and can't be iterated with for/of directly.  Its forEach method is its own special child node iterator.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that code. (changed snapshot.val -> child.val() ) But, I got same output. For / of is executed only once... Because, "snapshot.forEach(child => array.push(child))" is executed only once. "array" has only one element.

Comment: Did you make sure the process waits until the promise returned by the top level async function is fully resolved?  Are you sure that the array has only one element (did you try to print its length)?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem where the array.push(child) was getting executed only once. Hence adding to Doug's solution we need to do something like this so that the forEach loop does not exit before completing the entire process:

```
async function () {
    const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref("/path/").once("value")
    const array = []
    snapshot.forEach((child: any) => {
       array.push(child)
       return false
    })
    for (const child of array) {
       await sleep(1000)
       console.log(snapshot.val)
    }
 }
```